# PHP - cURL Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, curl

When I try and grab a value from the cURL response. I am getting a `Illegal string offset 'type' in`. When I remove the index value and just do `$resp_orders`. It returns the whole response fine.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/<companynumber>');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow http 3xx redirects
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "AUTH_KEY" . ":" . "");
        $resp_orders = curl_exec($ch); // execute

        print_r($resp_orders['company_name']);
```

Comment: What does `echo $resp_orders;` give?

Comment: `$resp_orders = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);`?

Answer (score 0):

curl_exec() is going to return a string. Assuming the result back is suppose to be a JSON result, then you need to json_decode it an array:

> $resp_orders_json = curl_exec($ch);
>
> $resp_orders = json_decode($resp_orders_json, true);

Comment: When i return $resp_orders it throws an error:  `Array to string conversion in`

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of: print_r($resp_orders['company_name']);

remove ['company_name'] just print_r($resp_orders);